# Using Indy Server's multiple bindings as separate sockets?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I'm still getting used to Indy, being a multi-threaded socket system with vast capabilities. One of the big things I've seen is how a server socket can have a number of different bindings. For example, you could have 3 bindings for 3 ports on the same IP address. I'm using Indy 10 on Delphi XE2.

I'm re-building an old system of mine which uses the old fashioned `TServerSocket` and `TClientSocket` components from `ScktComps` and re-doing it with Indy `TIdTCPServer` and `TIdTCPClient`. The old system actually consists of 3 completely different server/client sockets on each end, each socket serving a distinct purpose, and working together - similar to how FTP uses one socket for binary data and the other socket for commands.

Is it possible to mimic three separate server/client sockets within the same component using these bindings? It would be great if I can declare just one server socket with 3 ports bound, and same on the client, connected to 3 different ports on the server. All I would like to do is eliminate the need to create 3 separate server/client socket components and combine them into one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use a single `TIdTCPServer` to manage multiple ports at a time.  On the client side, you still need 3 distinct client components to connect to the different ports, though.

Create 3 entries in the `TIdTCPServer.Bindings` collection, one for each local IP/Port that you want to listen on, where the `TIdSocketHandle.Port` property would be the equivilent of the `TServerSocket.Port` property.  `TServerSocket` does not natively support binding to a specific IP (though it can be done with some manual work), but the `TIdSocketHandle.IP` property is used for that purpose, where a blank string is equivilent to `INADDR_ANY`.

In the `TIdCPServer.OnConnect`, `TIdCPServer.OnDisconnect`, and `TIdCPServer.OnExecute` events, you can use the `TIdContext.Binding.IP` and `TIdContext.Binding.Port` properties to differentiate which binding the calling socket is connected to.

A common use of this is to support SSL and non-SSL clients on different ports, such as for protocols like POP3 and SMTP which support implicit and explicit SSL/TLS on different ports.  `TIdHTTPServer` does this for supporting `HTTP` and `HTTPS` urls on a single server (you can use the `TIdHTTPServer.OnQuerySSLPort` to customize which ports use SSL/TLS versus not).

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.StartButtonCick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;

  with IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
  begin
    IP := ...;
    Port := 2000;
  end;

  with IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
  begin
    IP := ...;
    Port := 2001;
  end;

  with IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
  begin
    IP := ...;
    Port := 2002;
  end;

  IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  case AContext.Binding.Port of
    2000: begin
      // do something...
    end;
    2001: begin
      // do something else...
    end;
    2002: begin
      // do yet something else ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Awesome, just wondering is each port using its own thread or most probably all 3 in the same context thread?

Comment: Each entry in the `Bindings` collection runs in its own thread accepting inbound connections on its respective port. Each accepted client connection then runs in its own thread as well. So if you have 3 `Bindings` entries and 3 connected clients, that is 6 threads running.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: So to be completely clear, with no clients, I have 3 threads, one for each binding. Then, each client which is created generates 3 new threads. So it's `BindingCount + (ClientCount * BindingCount) = ThreadCount` right?

Comment: Not exactly. Each `Binding` runs in 1 thread, and each client runs in 1 thread, so `BindingCount + ClientCount = ThreadCount`.

Comment: I meant actually 1 "Client" = 3 "Sockets" so if one machine connects 3 sockets to this 1 server, one to each port (binding), that will create 3 context classes (threads) or one for all 3?

Comment: The server would create 3 context threads, one for each connection.